# Jquery sortable UI doesn't work with flexbox order-*

Tags: css, flexbox, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm facing troubles when I combine a sortable Jquery UI whit a bootstrap flexbox class order-*

When I stablish a order-* class inside a sortable container, the sortable functionality doesn't work. I can drag the item but when I release it, the element returns to its initial position. If I don't use the class order-*, the sortable functionality works fine.

It seems that the flexbox class order-* prevails over the sortable functionality. I thought about destroy the class order-* once load the html, but is a weird solution.

What I want to achieve is to show the order desired by the user and that the new order be saved when ordering

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
          $( ".sortable" ).sortable({ placeholder: "ui-state-highlight" });
          $( ".sortable" ). 
     });
</script> 

<!--Works Fine-->
<div id="main" class="sortable d-flex flex-row">
     <div style="background-color:coral; width:50px;">1</div>
     <div style="background-color:lightblue; width:50px;">3</div>
     <div style="background-color:lightgreen; width:50px;" >2</div>
     <div style="background-color:pink; width:50px;">4</div>
</div>

<!--doesn't work-->
<div id="main" class="sortable d-flex flex-row">
     <div style="background-color:coral; width:50px;" class="order-1">1</div>
     <div style="background-color:lightblue; width:50px;" class="order-3">3</div>
     <div style="background-color:lightgreen; width:50px;" class="order-2">2</div>
     <div style="background-color:pink; width:50px;" class="order-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: that `order` class is from bootstrap not from flexbox. It adds a flexbox order style to the element. Basically you want to change the `order` class depending on where you ' moved ' the element ? Why use the `order` class in the first place ? And please make a working example of your current situation ( code snippet )

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle or an inline code snippet